# Flask-Admin User Read/Write Settings Per Row

Tags: sql, flask, sqlalchemy, admin

Say I have User and Subuser tables, where a User can have many Subusers. How can I only allow the logged in user (current_user) to view only the Subusers who are a part of the User? I.e. `Subuser.user_id == current_user.id`. I get I can do this by a filter, but this must be forced and not optional.

I'm using the SQLAlchemy backend if that helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty simple to override the queries that are produced by the backend in Flask Admin - you can do some quite complex things.  Remember to override all of the below - especially get_one().

```
class BaseModelView(ModelView):
    def is_accessible(self):
        # if not authenticated we can't see this
        if not login.current_user.is_authenticated():
            return False

        return True

    def get_query(self):
        return query.filter(self.model.parent_user_id.any(id=login.current_user.id))

    def get_count_query(self):
        # faster count query!
        query = self.session.query(func.count('*')).select_from(self.model).filter(self.model.location_id == login.current_user.id)

        return query

    def get_one(self, id):
        """
            Return a single model by its id.

            :param id:
                Model id
        """
        result = self.session.query(self.model).get(iterdecode(id))

        # if the users location does not exist and she is only allowed to edit locations they control
        if login.current_user.id != result.parent_user_id:
            app.logger.warn('You are not allowed to edit entries for this user.')
            abort(404)

        return result
```

Comment: This is what works for me:`def get_query(self):
        return session.query(Login).filter(Login.id == login.current_user.id)`

Comment: And: `def get_count_query(self):        return session.query(func.count(Login)).filter(Login.id == login.current_user.id)`

You have to `from sqlalchemy import func`